# how to show a rule in prolog by passing a list with more items

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a uni project using Prolog, I find it hard to explain my codes so I'll just insert it here (this is not the actual codes to my project but its the same idea)

```
getlist1([H|T]):- read(X), not(X=end), H=X, getlist1(T).
getlist1([]).
getlist2([H|T]):- read(X), not(X=end), H=X, getlist1(T).
getlist2([]).


go:-write('select from the following:\n1.red 2.yellow 3.blue\n(type end if done)'),
     getlist1(R),sort(R,R2),
     write('select from the following:\n1.green 2.orange 3.pink\n(type end if done)'),
     getlist2(E),sort(E,E2),
     u(R2,E2).

u([1,2],[2]):-write('one').
u([1],[2,3]):-write('two').
u(_,_):-write('try again').
```

so now for example say that the user entered 1,2,3 for the first list
and 2 for the second list, I want the first rule u([1,2],[2]) to show, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work :

```
% getlist1/1 and getlist2/1 were the same so one getlist/1 is enough
getlist([H|T]):- read(H), H \== end, getlist(T).
getlist([]).

go:-write('select from the following:\n1.red 2.yellow 3.blue\n(type end if done)'),
     getlist(R),sort(R,R2),
     write('select from the following:\n1.green 2.orange 3.pink\n(type end if done)'),
     getlist(E),sort(E,E2),
     once(u(R2,E2)).

u([1,2|_],[2]):-write('one').
u([1],[2,3]):-write('two').
u(_,_):-write('try again').
```

By just adding `|_` the user can add any number >2 to the first list and still the first rule will show.